# QML. how to invoke the function of loader source item in the outside

Tags: qt, qml

blow codes are not working.

- main.qml

```
ListView {
    model: some_model
    delegate: Loader {
        source: 'xxx.qml'
    }
}

Button {
    id: idButton
    onClicked: foo_all()
}

function foo_all() {
    for (var i = 0; i < idListView.count; i++) {
        var modelItem = idListView.childAt(i)
        modelItem.foo_of_xxx()
    }
}
```

- xxx.qml

```
Item {
    function foo_of_xxx() {
        // bla bla
    }
}
```

i wanna invoke the function of loaded model items in the main.qml
how to do that?

Comment: You are already doing something, so specify what exactly is not working. Please provide [mcve], not the bla-bla code. Also there is no `childAt()` function but [ListView.itemAtIndex](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-listview.html#itemAtIndex-method).

Answer (score 0):

You are simply missing the `item` property of the `Loader` (and as mention, the `childAt` should be `itemAtIndex`):

```
function foo_all() {
    for (var i = 0; i < idListView.count; i++) {
        var modelItem = idListView.itemAtIndex(i)
        modelItem.item.foo_of_xxx()
    }
}
```